# Setting up Selenium Grid - A Second Node on MAC -Registration Failure

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

Tried to setup a Selenium node on Mac using:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar -role node \
-hub http://<<Hub Ip>> :4444/grid/regsiter -port 5557 \
-browser browserName=firefox,platform=MAC \
-remoteHost http://<<Remote Ip>>:5557
```

**Error**:

> 11:34:11.014 INFO - Adding browserName=firefox,platform=MAC 
>   11:34:11.016 INFO - Adding browserName=chrome,platform=MAC 
>   11:35:27.004 WARN - **error getting the parameters from the hub. The
>   node may end up with wrong timeouts**.Connect to **Hub  IP**:80 [/**Hub
>   IP**] failed: Operation timed out  11:35:27.028 INFO - Java: Oracle
>   Corporation 23.25-b01  11:35:27.028 INFO - OS: Mac OS X 10.10.2 x86_64
>   11:35:27.038 INFO - v2.44.0, with Core v2.44.0. Built from revision
>   76d78cf  11:35:27.198 INFO - Default driver
>   org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped:
>   registration capabilities Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS,
>   ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=}]
>   does not match with current platform: MAC  11:35:27.254 INFO -
>   RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to:
>   http://127.0.0.1:5556/wd/hub  11:35:27.256 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x 
>   11:35:27.259 INFO - Started
>   HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver] 
>   11:35:27.260 INFO - Started
>   HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]  11:35:27.261 INFO -
>   Started HttpContext[/,/]  11:35:27.294 INFO - Started
>   org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@5f6b70e1  11:35:27.295
>   INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]  11:35:27.299 INFO - Started
>   SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:5556  11:35:27.299 INFO - Started
>   org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@2c11c55b  11:35:27.346 INFO - using the
>   json request :
>   {"class":"org.openqa.grid.common.RegistrationRequest","configuration":{"register":true,"port":5556,"host":"<>","proxy":"org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy","browser":"browserName\u003dfirefox,platform\u003dMAC","maxSession":5,"role":"node","hubHost":"**Hub
>   IP**","registerCycle":5000,"hub":"http://<Remote
>   IP:5556","remoteHost":"http://**Remote Ip**:5556"},"capabilities":[{"seleniumProtocol":"WebDriver","platform":"MAC","browserName":"firefox"},{"seleniumProtocol":"WebDriver","platform":"MAC","browserName":"chrome"}]}
>   11:35:27.347 INFO - Starting auto register thread. Will try to
>   register every 5000 ms.  11:35:27.347 INFO - **Registering the node to
>   hub :http://**Remote IP**:-1/grid/register  11:36:43.151 INFO -
>   **couldn't register this node : Error sending the registration request**

Comment: Check your command: it says -hub (..) /regsiter

Comment: I was getting an error- connection timed out. But able to see on grid console ..like this. drive.google.com/file/d/0B_gwHb72nZGURTRVX2N0cDk4THM/… --whats that mean? Do I need any connection software for this ...I tried using TeamViewer

Answer (score 0):

Your command appears to have a typo.

```
-hub http://<<Hub Ip>> :4444/grid/regsiter
                      ^              ^^
                     here         and here
```

Change this to:

```
-hub http://<<hubip>>:4444/grid/register
                     ^             ^^
                  no space   fix transposition
```

Additionally, I've always used the directive `-hubUrl`, not `-hub`.  They may be synonyms, but if this solution I provided above still does not work, try **also** replacing `-hub` with `-hubUrl`.

Comment: you need to execute that on the hub machine

Comment: I was getting an error- connection timed out. But able to see on grid console ..like this.   https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_gwHb72nZGURTRVX2N0cDk4THM/view?usp=sharing  --whats that mean? Do I need any connection software for this ...I tried using TeamViewer